How to attain Moksha? Which sacred texts to follow with regards to Moksha?
I want to know the answer from authentic and traditional sources.

This question is similar to: Approach to the Ultimate/Absolute Truth (Jnana). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
